# Group in regex that matches every substring that doesnt start with a specific character

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am trying to write a group in a regex that matches every substring except for the ones that start with a ' **"** '

The long story short of my regex is : something that starts with 2 personal names and ends with a 10-digit id. Mainly I have 3 groups: the names, the middle part and the ID.

So it has to match

*Jennifer Ann* **from New York, "Wisdom" str, bl. 54, В, with id** *1234567890*

in

```
her name was Jennifer Ann from New York, "Wisdom" str, bl 54, B, with id 1234567890 which is very rare
```

but not to match anything in :

```
her name was Jennifer Ann" from New York, "Wisdom" str, bl 54, B, with id 1234567890 which is very rare
```

because of the quotes after Ann. Right now my middle part group looks like this:

**(?'compositeMiddle'.*?)** which matches everything. I want to make it match everything except for the substrings that start with: **"**

Comment: did you want to match the whole line or the part?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the whole thing

Comment: is this `Jennifer Ann from New York, "Wisdom" str, bl. 54, В, with id 1234567890` isn't your input? How regex would know, these are person's name and these are city names.

Comment: lets suppose that I know how to make the difference :) But it is a good point though :)

Comment: have a look at this http://regex101.com/r/zT5mS5/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj This one gets the closest to what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[^"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\b\d{10}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zT5mS5/1)

`(?:[^"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?` first the regex engine takes this `[^"']` then combined it with the following `*` and tries to match any character but not of `'` or `"` zero or more times. If it founds a double quotes, the first pattern `[^"']` got failed and the regex engine chooses the next that is, `"[^"]*"`. This pattern would matches the strings like `"foo"`, `"bar"` etc. If it founds an `'` symbol then the control transfers to the third pattern `'[^']*'`. So it matches only the properly quoted strings if they present.

Comment: can you explain me the (?: ... part?

Comment: Well, I tried to add another symbol that represents quotes but in a different locale and I just modified the first: [^"'] to [^"'”] but it fails for the cases:
Jeniffer Ann” something else "in the tring" id 1234567890

Answer (score 0):

```
(?'compositeMiddle'[^"].*)
```

The `[abc]` pattern is a collection of matching characters, and it can be negated by the `^`.

Comment: It doesnt really work. I tried it but it keeps on matching the content with quotes in the begining

Comment: ('first'[A-Z][a-z]+)\s(?'second'[A-Z][a-z]+)(?'composite'[^"].*)id\s[\d]{10}